# updating recyclerView in onResume ();

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview

I have encountered some problems in "recreating" an adapter from the recyclerView in the onResume method.
Basically, this is my scheme.

```
MainActivit  -ViewPager
   - fragment A (has a recyclerView)
   - fragment B (nop)
   - fragment C (nop)
   - fragment D (it has the same recyclerView as the framgnet A)
```

**onResume I always call for**

```
> myCustomAdapter adapter = new myCustomAdapter (
> mListItems,getContext(),ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId(),
> "type");
>                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

but this causes some problems, like when I go back to MainActivity from another activity. For example.

```
Activityt A
 - click on item in recylerView
 - start Activity B

Activity B
user does some actions, sees some news, and returns to Activity A.

Activity A
recreates the adapter and set recyclerView.setAdapter (new Adapter);
this is slow, causes a delay of 2 seconds after onBackPressed is pressed in Activity B.
```

I also have a **setMenuVisibility** method that also does the same thing as onResume, because as informed in fragment D, I have the recyclerView in fragment A, so if a user makes some change in the recyclerView that is in fragment D, I need update the recyclerView of fragment  A when the user returns to it.

**Why the same recyclerView in Fragment D is in Fragment A?**

We can consider the following, in fragment A, I have a recyclerView that contains only the "user interests", and in fragment D, I have user information such as user name, photo, etc ... and also the "user interests".

**Conclusion:** The problem is when I return from Activity B to Activity A, and when I alternate between fragment A and fragment D in viewPager, this causes a delay for the re-creation of the adapter.

What should I do in this situation?

I apologize for this horrible English, I'm using google translator.

Comment: are you loading images in the RecyclerView items?

Comment: I am, and maybe in the wrong way. I need to add an amount of 8 ImageView with different images, in each line of the recyclerView.

Comment: The image loading is causing the lag, use an image loading library like Glide or Picasso

Comment: I just removed the code that adds the ImageViews and this really "solved" the problem, but I really need the ImageViews.
I already use Picasso.
Currently I'm adding the imageViews as follows.

holder.ContainerImageViews.addView (imageView);

When removing this code, the delay stopped occurring, do you think that if I add 8 imageViews in xml, will it make any difference in performance? or will the same delay continue? each imageView has a size of 45dp / 45dp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a `Scope Problem`. You need to define `adapter` in somewhere class member.

1. If you want the data presented in Fragment A and Fragment D different, then make `adapter` as a member of each other, and init it in each `Fragment.onCreate()`. So it won't recreate adapter evert time. (Make sure ViewPager has enough cache number, or it will still recreate the whole non-cached Fragment)
2. If you want the FragmentA and FragmentD display identical data or part of the same data, create `adapter` in `MainActivity.onCreate` and pass it as parameters into FragmentA, FragmentD.

It is not need to recreate `adapter` every time `onResume` because it's really a heavy job. No need to change any view layer attributes. Make sure the data(adapter) which you want to share is in the same scope or can pass to it.

For example:

```
//MainActivity
private Adapter adapter;

void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    //...other stuff
    adapter = new myCustomAdapter (mListItems,getContext(),ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId(), "type");
}
public Adapter getAdapter(){ return adapter;}


//FragmentA or FragmentD
void onCreateView(){
    MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity(); //This fragment should be created with `MainActivity`
    recyclerView.setAdapter(activity.getAdapter());
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks. This clarified some things to me, can you provide me with a sample code to share the adapter between the fragments? how should I pass this activity data to the fragments? forgive-me and my arrogance, I'm beginner with android programming.

Comment: Hello, does this really work, but the problem remains, how to "notify" a change in the adapter? I tried using adapter.notifySetDataChange (); but this does not change the adapter data in recyclerView, how to solve this? Thank you!

Comment: Where do you change dataset(list.add()), it must be in main thread and recyclerview will populate itself. If changed in a background thread, the notifySetDataChange should in a activity.post(runnable) block

Answer (score 0):

Do not set set image using "src" attribute of ImageView when dealing with large images or multiple small images
Use an image loading library like Glide or Picasso.
The following snippet is for Glide v4

```
Glide.with(context).load(<url_or_res_id>).into(imageView)
```

You can pass url as string. Or if you are loading images from drawable, you can pass its resource id (eg. R.drawable.image_id)

Comment: I'm using: Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(img_profilePicture);
Please check my comment and tell me what you think about the holder.ContainerView.addView (img_profilePicture);

Comment: you are not using recyclerview's ability of recycling. Dont use addView, instead load every view from an array list and call adapter.notifyDatasetChanged() after adding item to the list. Recyclerview will manage the rest

Comment: So, you recommend that I add 8 imageViews in xml, leave them as Gone, and just setVisible (View.Visible); when necessary?

Comment: No, let them be visible, just remove `src` attribute in xml. Create 8 ImageView variables and use a libary to load image into each image view. (according to what I understood, you have 8 imageViews in each list item)